# Is there any default strategy to prepare application for a resolution change?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, resolution

How to prepare a Silverlight or WPF application to change from a big resolution to a small resolution?

I guess using dockpanel strategy only works for changing from a small to a big resolution.

So, is there any default strategy? Thanks.

Problem: I have a button the ends in the pixel 1024, 768. And I change the resolution to 800x600.

Comment: I'm starting to think that there is no good solution for this. Only zoom. :O

Comment: Have you looked the the OnArrange/OnMeasure process that controls go through when fitting themselves into a particular resolution? The link here explains in more detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think doing this way is better:

```
ScrollViewer Background="GreenYellow" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="layoutRoot">
        Canvas Width="1024" Height="768">
            dataInput:Label Height="50" Name="label1" Width="100" Canvas.Left="540" Canvas.Top="131" Content="aeeeeeeee" />
            Button Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="131" Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" />
            Button Canvas.Left="937" Canvas.Top="147" Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button2" Width="75" />
            Button Canvas.Left="510" Canvas.Top="21" Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button3" Width="75" />
            Button Canvas.Left="482" Canvas.Top="550" Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button4" Width="75" />
        /Canvas>
    /ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I had a similar issue. As a workaround I surrounded the window content in a **Viewbox**.

Users that used 1024x768 instead of 1280x1024 see the application content smaller, but they preferred this than scrolling all the time. (WPF)

I'll have to work on this for our next project, let's hope somebody has better ideas!

Comment: wow, this is problably awesome. I will study that. Later I check the awnser. Thanks.

Comment: @Seva - the issue we have is that is resolutions are too different the view can be 'stretched'. For example, if you use the application on a laptop wide screen. But so far in general people prefers this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could design your layout to Stretch and designing it with 800x600 in mind, so whenever the layout becomes larger than 800x600 it will fit. But...

if you really want something fancy, detect the change in the window size/ActualHeight and ActualWidth (using SizeChanged) then scale the the application according to size via code (using dynamic transforms).

For example, in the "LayoutRoot" in your main view:

```
var x = new ScaleTransform();
            x.ScaleX = .5; // Do fancy computation here
            x.ScaleY = .5; // Do fancy computation here
            this.LayoutRoot.RenderTransform = x;
```

Just an idea, i mean if the screen is bigger than your design you enlarge and vice versa.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I hope to not need to implement that, but its a solution ^^. Thanks

Comment: well, I thought the code was worse. You can render an entire layout! This very good. That's the best awnser for me =)